# Reactstrap: understanding arrow functions and Navbar alignment

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap, reactstrap

I have a small problem.

1). In the example code for the Reactstrap Navbar, the navbar class is now an arrow function (where do I learn about this?).

2). When I compile my code, the  tag is basically attached to the  tag on the top-left side of the header instead of being placed on the top-right side of the navbar (how do i fix this?).

```
const TopNav = (props) => {
    const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);

    const toggle = () => setIsOpen(!isOpen);

    return (
      <div>
        <Navbar color="light" light expand="md">
          <NavbarBrand href="/">flying car dealership</NavbarBrand>
          <NavbarToggler onClick={toggle} />

          <Collapse isOpen={isOpen} navbar>
            <Nav className="mr-auto" navbar>
              <NavItem>
                <NavLink href="/">Home</NavLink>
              </NavItem>

              <UncontrolledDropdown nav inNavbar>
                <DropdownToggle nav caret>
                  Flying Cars
                </DropdownToggle>
                <DropdownMenu right>
                  <DropdownItem>
                    Option 1
                  </DropdownItem>
                  <DropdownItem>
                    Option 2
                  </DropdownItem>
                  <DropdownItem divider />
                  <DropdownItem>
                    Reset
                  </DropdownItem>
                </DropdownMenu>
              </UncontrolledDropdown>

              <NavItem>
                <NavLink href='/find-a-dealer'>Find A Dealer</NavLink>  
              </NavItem>
              <NavItem>
                  <NavLink href='/build-and-price'>Build And Price</NavLink>
              </NavItem>

            </Nav>
          </Collapse>
        </Navbar>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Thank You!!!

Comment: In my Navbar I just gave each item a `className` and moved them with CSS. Does that not work?

Comment: @WebbH EUREKA!!! (that worked)...